# Using table data in SSMS'08 as an '03 access form header and combining several rows into one. Audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have an audit table which displays data as so:

```
 PK                      FieldName  OldValue    NewValue    UpdateDate   
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------  

 <orderline=485040867>   qtyrec     0           1           2016-05-03 09:09:04.223  
 <orderline=485040867>   statcode   RD          RC          2016-05-03 09:09:04.223  
 <orderline=485040867>   qty        NULL        1           2016-04-28 03:24:57.490  
 <orderline=485040867>   qtyrec     NULL        0           2016-04-28 03:24:57.490  
 <orderline=485040867>   statcode   NULL        NP          2016-04-28 03:24:57.490  
 <orderline=485040867>   batch      NULL        MRP280416A  2016-04-28 17:01:57.160  
 <orderline=485040867>   statcode   NP          OR          2016-04-28 17:01:57.160  
 <orderline=485040867>   statcode   OR          RD          2016-04-29 05:06:29.100
```

As may hopefully be clear from this, this table logs when various things are updated or inserted for an orderline. Recieved quantity for example. What I would like to do is create a form in access to display all changes which occured at a given date + time on one row for any order.
This would involve using the records in the FieldName column as column headers and my end product would hopefully look something along the lines of

```
PK                       qty    qtyrec    statcode    batch      Updatedate
orderline = 485040867    1      0         NP                     2016-04-28 03:24:57.490
orderline = 485040867    1      0         OR          MRP280416A 2016-04-28 17:01:57.160
orderline = 485040867    1      1         RC          MRP280416A 2016-05-03 09:09:04.223
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? creating the form, connecting to sqlserver, applying the filter, something else?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldve probably been more clear. Creating the form is my main issue. I'm not sure how I would combine the rows to display how I wish, or get the FieldName records to actively work as shown above.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the issue. Do you need help with the SQL query or the form? Is this the type of form you're creating https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your example input for a variable table like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    PK NVARCHAR(255),
    FieldName NVARCHAR(255),
    OldValue NVARCHAR(255),
    NewValue NVARCHAR(255),
    UpdateDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
    ('<orderline=485040867>', 'qty', NULL, '1', '2016-04-28 03:24:57.490'),
    ('<orderline=485040867>', 'qtyrec', NULL, '0', '2016-04-28 03:24:57.490'),
    ('<orderline=485040867>', 'statcode', NULL, 'NP', '2016-04-28 03:24:57.490'),
    ('<orderline=485040867>', 'qtyrec', '0', '1', '2016-05-03 09:09:04.223'),
    ('<orderline=485040867>', 'statcode', 'RD', 'RC', '2016-05-03 09:09:04.223'),
    ('<orderline=485040867>', 'batch', NULL, 'MRP280416A', '2016-04-28 17:01:57.160'),
    ('<orderline=485040867>', 'statcode', 'NP', 'OR', '2016-04-28 17:01:57.160'),
    ('<orderline=485040867>', 'statcode', 'OR', 'RD', '2016-04-29 05:06:29.100');
```

I think you would want to group by PK and UpdateDate. So I used a subselect for each column like this:

```
SELECT a.PK
, (SELECT TOP 1 NewValue
    FROM @t b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'qty'
    AND b.PK = a.PK
    AND b.UpdateDate <= a.UpdateDate
    ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC) AS qty
, (SELECT TOP 1 NewValue
    FROM @t b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'qtyrec'
    AND b.PK = a.PK
    AND b.UpdateDate <= a.UpdateDate
    ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC) AS qtyrec
, (SELECT TOP 1 NewValue
    FROM @t b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'statcode'
    AND b.PK = a.PK
    AND b.UpdateDate <= a.UpdateDate
    ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC) AS statcode
, (SELECT TOP 1 NewValue
    FROM @t b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'batch'
    AND b.PK = a.PK
    AND b.UpdateDate <= a.UpdateDate
    ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC) AS batch
, a.UpdateDate
FROM (
    SELECT PK
    , UpdateDate
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY PK, UpdateDate
) a
```

This is not really fast. You could alternatively use an outer apply like following example

```
SELECT a.PK
, qty.NewValue AS qty
, qtyrec.NewValue AS qtyrec
, statcode.NewValue AS statcode
, batch.NewValue AS batch
, a.UpdateDate
FROM (
    SELECT PK
    , UpdateDate
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY PK, UpdateDate
) a
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 OldValue, NewValue
    FROM @t b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'qty'
    AND b.PK = a.PK
    AND b.UpdateDate <= a.UpdateDate
    ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC
) qty
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 OldValue, NewValue
    FROM @t b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'qtyrec'
    AND b.PK = a.PK
    AND b.UpdateDate <= a.UpdateDate
    ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC
) qtyrec
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 OldValue, NewValue
    FROM @t b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'statcode'
    AND b.PK = a.PK
    AND b.UpdateDate <= a.UpdateDate
    ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC
) statcode
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 OldValue, NewValue
    FROM @t b
    WHERE b.FieldName = 'batch'
    AND b.PK = a.PK
    AND b.UpdateDate <= a.UpdateDate
    ORDER BY b.UpdateDate DESC
) batch
```

but there didn't seem to be any difference in runtimes/io, just the query plan is different. I couldn't come up with a good pivot solution, but you could take a look at this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much! This has got me exactly what I wanted. However, I also require to be able to join onto our Orderline table. I would need to join on orderline, which is displayed in this table as 

        <orderline = 485040867> 

But displayed in the orderline table as just 485040867 under the orderline column. I have tried to join on orderline with a LIKE statement, something akin to 

         SELECT * FROM orderline ol INNER JOIN Audit a ON '%' + a.PK + '%' LIKE ol.orderline

But this has not worked.

Comment: Simplest way, remove the unwanted characters, as these seem to be static: `SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(PK,'<orderline=',''),'>','') AS int) AS Orderline`

Comment: Thank you so much again! This has provided me with all I should (hopefully) need! Time to get building this form... 
This question can now be closed.